# X-editable element inside button-popup gets hidden when clicked anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

The x-editable popover form behaves differently when an editable element is defined inside a button. Which is exactly what I wanted to do. When the popup shows, try clicking any element from within the popup - this will close the form altogether, opposite to the normal behavior.

Here is the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" id="btn-inside">
inside a button&nbsp; 
<a href="#" id="model-inside-button" data-value="3" class="editable" tabindex="-1">3</a>
</button>

<script>
$('#model-inside-button').editable();

$('#btn-inside').click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $('#model-inside-button').editable('toggle');
});
</script>
```

I also prepared a fiddle of this showing the two buttons - one that works and one that doesn't.

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jfaquinojr/MALgZ/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that wants to achieve the same UI goal in the question please do this instead.

change the following code:

```
$('#model-inside-button').editable('toggle');
```

to this:

```
$('#model-inside-button').editable('show');
```

Note that there is no IsVisible or similar function exposed by the library so the 'show' method will be called repetitively each time the user clicks anywhere on the popover form (e.stopPropagation, e.stopImmediatePropagation, and e.preventDefault does not seem to help in this area).